# Unable to change li Background Color on Hover

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/NRZeD/) and let me know why I am not able to change the background color of the li on hover?

```
<ul class="inline">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.inline li{
    width:18% !important;
    background:#FFF  !important;
}
.inline li: hover{
    background:#A5A5A5  !important;
}
```

Comment: remove the space between li and hover

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extra space before hover.

```
.inline li:hover{
    background:#A5A5A5  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The space between `li` and `:hover` is valid CSS, but not in this case. Using `li :hover` will apply styles when you hover over any descendant of the `li`. What you are using is invalid CSS. You can't have a colon between an element and a pseudo-class. So by using `li:hover`, you are specifiying the styles when the `li` is being hovered over.

I would also recommend that you not use `!important`, because it can cause some problems later down the road. Use more specific DOM selectors, like `ul.inline li:hover`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRZeD/13/)

Answer (score 2):

[Edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRZeD/1/). Remove the empty space before `hover`.

```
.inline li:hover{

    background:#A5A5A5  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space before hover. It should be:

```
.inline li:hover {
Stylings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it s because you are using **!important** on the not hover li and there is a space between **li** and **:hover**

```
.inline li{
    width:18%!important;
    background:#FFF;
}

.inline li:hover{
    background:#A5A5A5!important;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NRZeD/14/